# Replace values from a dataframe with values from another with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes with identical columns, but different values and different number of rows.

```py
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'Region': ['Africa','Africa','Africa','Africa','Africa','Africa','Africa','Africa','Asia','Asia','Asia','Asia'],
         'Country': ['South Africa','South Africa','South Africa','South Africa','South Africa','South Africa','South Africa','South Africa','Japan','Japan','Japan','Japan'],
         'Product': ['ABC','ABC','ABC','ABC','XYZ','XYZ','XYZ','XYZ','DEF','DEF','DEF','DEF'],
         'Year': [2016, 2017, 2018, 2019,2016, 2017, 2018, 2019,2016, 2017, 2018, 2019],
         'Price': [500, 400, 0,450,750,0,0,890,500,470,0,415]}

data1 = {'Region': ['Africa','Africa','Africa','Africa','Africa','Africa','Asia','Asia'],
         'Country': ['South Africa','South Africa','South Africa','South Africa','South Africa','South Africa','Japan','Japan'],
         'Product': ['ABC','ABC','ABC','ABC','XYZ','XYZ','DEF','DEF'],
         'Year': [2016, 2017, 2018, 2019,2016, 2017,2016, 2017],
         'Price': [200, 100, 30,750,350,120,400,370]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

`df` is the complete dataset but with some old values, whereas `df2` only has the updated values. I want to replace all the values that are in `df` with the values in `df2`, all while keeping the values from `df` that aren't in `df2`.

So for example, in `df`, the value for `Country` = Japan, for `Product` = DEF, in `Year` = 2016, the `Price` should be updated from 470 to 400. The same for 2017, while 2018 and 2019 stay the same.

So far I have the following code that doesn't seem to work:

```py
common_index = ['Region','Country','Product','Year']
df = df.set_index(common_index)
df2 = df2.set_index(common_index)
df.update(df2, overwrite = True)
```

But this only updates `df` with the values from `df2` and deletes everything else.

Expected output should look like this:

```
data3 = {'Region': ['Africa','Africa','Africa','Africa','Africa','Africa','Africa','Africa','Asia','Asia','Asia','Asia'],
         'Country': ['South Africa','South Africa','South Africa','South Africa','South Africa','South Africa','South Africa','South Africa','Japan','Japan','Japan','Japan'],
         'Product': ['ABC','ABC','ABC','ABC','XYZ','XYZ','XYZ','XYZ','DEF','DEF','DEF','DEF'],
         'Year': [2016, 2017, 2018, 2019,2016, 2017, 2018, 2019,2016, 2017, 2018, 2019],
         'Price': [200, 100, 30,750,350,120,0,890,400,370,0,415]}

df3 = pd.DataFrame(data3)
```

Any suggestions on how I can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
df.update(df.merge(df2, on=['Region', 'Country', 'Product', 'Year'],
                   how='left', suffixes=('_old', None)))
```

*NB. the `update` is **in place**.*

output:

```
    Region       Country Product  Year  Price
0   Africa  South Africa     ABC  2016  200.0
1   Africa  South Africa     ABC  2017  100.0
2   Africa  South Africa     ABC  2018   30.0
3   Africa  South Africa     ABC  2019  750.0
4   Africa  South Africa     XYZ  2016  350.0
5   Africa  South Africa     XYZ  2017  120.0
6   Africa  South Africa     XYZ  2018    0.0
7   Africa  South Africa     XYZ  2019  890.0
8     Asia         Japan     DEF  2016  400.0
9     Asia         Japan     DEF  2017  370.0
10    Asia         Japan     DEF  2018    0.0
11    Asia         Japan     DEF  2019  415.0
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```py
df['Price'].update(df.merge(df2, on=['Region', 'Country', 'Product', 'Year'], how='left')['Price_y'])
```

```
print(df)

    Region       Country Product  Year  Price
0   Africa  South Africa     ABC  2016    200
1   Africa  South Africa     ABC  2017    100
2   Africa  South Africa     ABC  2018     30
3   Africa  South Africa     ABC  2019    750
4   Africa  South Africa     XYZ  2016    350
5   Africa  South Africa     XYZ  2017    120
6   Africa  South Africa     XYZ  2018      0
7   Africa  South Africa     XYZ  2019    890
8     Asia         Japan     DEF  2016    400
9     Asia         Japan     DEF  2017    370
10    Asia         Japan     DEF  2018      0
11    Asia         Japan     DEF  2019    415
```

Comment: (almost) the same answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the case but what if `df2` carry something not listed in `df1`? Here I'm adding a row to `df2` with data Asia, Japan, DEF, 2020, 400.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data1 = {
    'Region': ['Africa','Africa','Africa','Africa',
               'Africa','Africa','Africa','Africa',
               'Asia','Asia','Asia','Asia'],
    'Country': ['South Africa','South Africa',
                'South Africa','South Africa','South Africa',
                'South Africa','South Africa','South Africa',
                'Japan','Japan','Japan','Japan'],
    'Product': ['ABC','ABC','ABC','ABC','XYZ','XYZ','XYZ',
                'XYZ','DEF','DEF','DEF','DEF'],
    'Year': [2016, 2017, 2018, 2019,2016, 2017, 2018,
             2019,2016, 2017, 2018, 2019],
    'Price': [500, 400, 0,450,750,0,0,890,500,
              470,0,415]}

data2 = {
    'Region': ['Africa','Africa','Africa','Africa','Africa',
               'Africa','Asia','Asia', 'Asia'],
    'Country': ['South Africa','South Africa','South Africa',
                'South Africa','South Africa',
                'South Africa','Japan','Japan', 'Japan'],
    'Product': ['ABC','ABC','ABC','ABC','XYZ','XYZ','DEF',
                'DEF', 'DEF'],
    'Year': [2016, 2017, 2018, 2019,2016, 2017,2016, 2017, 2020],
    'Price': [200, 100, 30,750,350,120,400,370, 400]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

Here I call `df1` the first dataframe instead of `df`. Then I'm adding few step so we know exactly what is going on.

First I rename `Price` to `Price_new` in `df2` then I'll do an outer join between the 2 dataframes.

```py
df2 = df2.rename(columns={"Price": "Price_new"})
cols_merge = ['Region', 'Country', 'Product', 'Year']
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how="outer", on=cols_merge)
```

which gives

```bash
    Region       Country Product  Year  Price  Price_new
0   Africa  South Africa     ABC  2016  500.0      200.0
1   Africa  South Africa     ABC  2017  400.0      100.0
2   Africa  South Africa     ABC  2018    0.0       30.0
3   Africa  South Africa     ABC  2019  450.0      750.0
4   Africa  South Africa     XYZ  2016  750.0      350.0
5   Africa  South Africa     XYZ  2017    0.0      120.0
6   Africa  South Africa     XYZ  2018    0.0        NaN
7   Africa  South Africa     XYZ  2019  890.0        NaN
8     Asia         Japan     DEF  2016  500.0      400.0
9     Asia         Japan     DEF  2017  470.0      370.0
10    Asia         Japan     DEF  2018    0.0        NaN
11    Asia         Japan     DEF  2019  415.0        NaN
12    Asia         Japan     DEF  2020    NaN      400.0
```

Now wherever `Price_new` is not null we update the `Price` column

```py
df["Price"] = np.where(
    df["Price_new"].notnull(),
    df["Price_new"],
    df["Price"])
```

The output being

```bash
    Region       Country Product  Year  Price  Price_new
0   Africa  South Africa     ABC  2016  200.0      200.0
1   Africa  South Africa     ABC  2017  100.0      100.0
2   Africa  South Africa     ABC  2018   30.0       30.0
3   Africa  South Africa     ABC  2019  750.0      750.0
4   Africa  South Africa     XYZ  2016  350.0      350.0
5   Africa  South Africa     XYZ  2017  120.0      120.0
6   Africa  South Africa     XYZ  2018    0.0        NaN
7   Africa  South Africa     XYZ  2019  890.0        NaN
8     Asia         Japan     DEF  2016  400.0      400.0
9     Asia         Japan     DEF  2017  370.0      370.0
10    Asia         Japan     DEF  2018    0.0        NaN
11    Asia         Japan     DEF  2019  415.0        NaN
12    Asia         Japan     DEF  2020  400.0      400.0
```

And you can evertually remove the extra column with

```py
df = df.drop(columns=["Price_new"])
```

## Note

The other solutions are great and I upvoted them. I added this to show you that sometime is better to use less specific code in order to have better control and maintainability in your code.